# ¿Es posible hacer que los links de hmtl (imagenes en este caso) se abran siempre en una misma ventana?

Tags: html, web

Antes de nada, comentar que no tengo ni idea de programacion de java o scripting.
mi pregunta es si es sencillo o posible, hacer que los enlaces de una web (va a ser un menu de fotos muy escueto), se abran siempre en una misma ventana.
El diagrama seria el siguiente:
Pc con dos monitores, uno tactil y otro una tele. La idea es que el menu de imagenes este visualizandose en el tactil, y cuando alguien pulse en el, se cargue la imagen siempre en la misma ventana de la tele. 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, podemos ayudarte, pero antes hace falta el código que tienes hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver el código no puedo ayudar mucho, pero por lo que te he entendido solo necesitarias utilizar el campo "target" dentro de tu html.

```
<a href="enlace.html" target="_ventana">texto o imagen</a>
```

De todas formas, si añades tu código o parte de él, se te podría ayudar más.